# moderncv \cvitemwithcomment text gets cut off if too long

Tags: moderncv

I have the following code:

```
\cvitemwithcomment{Lorem ipsum}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum}{}
```

The problem is when the text is too long, it doesn't wrap around to the second line instead it is just one long line of text that gets cut off. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE! `\cvitemwithcomment{Lorem ipsum}{\parbox{\lineweidth}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum} }{}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
\cvitemwithcomment{Lorem ipsum}{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum} }{}
\end{document}
```

it gives:

[image]